# SQL Pivot Function for 2 Column Table

Tags: sql, pivot

I have a file with id numbers and timestamps. Each id can have multiple timestamps, in addition to duplicate timestamps. I need to create a SQL pivot table out of these rows so one id is attached to multiple distinct timestamp columns. I have tried tutorials online and nothing is working so figured I would ask here. Sample dataset is below:

```
id          timestamp
17530018    5/23/12 12:41
20119410    5/28/12 2:40
20119410    5/28/12 2:40
20150453    6/6/12 20:52
20150453    6/6/12 20:52
20150453    6/6/12 19:45
20150453    6/6/12 19:45
20267495    6/22/12 19:50
20267495    6/22/12 19:50
20345259    6/30/12 19:15
20345259    6/30/12 19:15
20365779    7/5/12 1:29
20469785    7/30/12 10:19
20469785    7/30/12 10:19
17602687    7/30/12 15:29
20598000    8/9/12 20:45
20598000    8/9/12 20:45
20598000    8/9/12 22:37
20598000    8/9/12 22:37
20598000    8/10/12 20:40
20598000    8/10/12 20:40
20598000    8/12/12 0:51
20598000    8/12/12 0:51
20598000    8/12/12 1:00
20598000    8/12/12 1:00
20517115    8/14/12 1:34
20583314    8/14/12 1:33
20517115    8/14/12 1:34
20583314    8/14/12 1:33
```

Thank you in advance for any feedback/input/help.

Comment: What is the pivot supposed to look like? Numbered column headers for the dates?

Comment: Hi, It is supposed to have the id column, and then timestamp1, timestamp2 etc.

Comment: So yes, essentially numbered.

Comment: Are you sure you are not asking select distinct id, timestamp ? What is the output you expect to see? And also what is the backend.

Comment: Yes, distinct id and distinct timestamp. The backend data are on SQL.

Comment: SQL is not a backend it is a name for the language used by all SQL series backends. If distinct, then simply "select distinct id, timestamp from yourTable". It has nothing to do with pivoting then.

Comment: Each id has multiple timestamps that can either be duplicates or unique and need to show up in separate columns next to the id just like a pivot.

Answer (score 0):

```
with data as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by id order by "timestamp") as rn
    from T
)
select id,
    [1] as timestamp1, [2] as timestamp2, [3] as timestamp3,
    [4] as timestamp4, [5] as timestamp5, [6] as timestamp6,
    [7] as timestamp7, [8] as timestamp8, [9] as timestamp9,
    [10] as timestamp10
from data pivot (
    min("timestamp")
    for rn in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10])
) pvt;
```

This will only cover up to 10. The number of columns won't be dynamic.

Comment: Where did that magic 10 come from? Also how do you know the backend? This wouldn't work in many backends at all.

Comment: The timestamps can actually be a TBD number - is there a way to make it dynamic?

Comment: Shawn - thanks for the code - do you know why for some rows that only have one timestamp, they don't show up in timestamp1 and rather a different column?

Comment: @lifeonmars No, I'd have to see your data. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b5da77d8d8443c1718a692215b34409f

Comment: @shawnt00 I figured out the issue - thank you so much for this code and introducing me to dbfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are trying to say that you are using MS SQL Server and after pivoting this data like:

Id, ts1, ts2 ...

It would require dynamic SQL and at seconds level end result might have too many columns with few data in cells (then you could try doing that maybe at date level):

```
DECLARE @times NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT  @times = @times + QUOTENAME(convert(VARCHAR,[timestamp],120)) + ', '
FROM    myTable
GROUP BY convert(VARCHAR,[timestamp],120);

SET @times = LEFT(@times, LEN(@times) - 1);

SET @SQL = 'SELECT *
FROM
(
        SELECT  1 AS x, id, convert(VARCHAR,[timestamp],120) as [timestamp]
        FROM myTable     
) AS Tmp
    PIVOT(sum(x) FOR [timestamp] IN ('+@times+')) AS PVT
    ORDER BY 1;';

EXEC(@SQL);
```

Here is [DBFiddle demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6b5b9af583ac1f9cdbc2427951558cdf)